# Neo4j - Where not exists

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Today I was coding some sample queries and I stumbled in something.

Let's say that I have the following dataset:
[image: dataset]

If I query:

```
MATCH (c:company)-[:sells]->(p:product)<-[:taxes]-(t:tax)
WHERE NOT EXISTS {
    MATCH (p)<-[:taxes]-(t)
    WHERE t.name = 'tax2'
}
RETURN c,p
```

Then I get all the products that don't have ONLY tax2 ( product1 and product3 )

But if I query:

```
MATCH (c:company)-[:sells]->(p:product)<-[:taxes]-(t:tax)
WHERE NOT EXISTS {
    MATCH (p)<-[:taxes]-(t2)
    WHERE t2.name = 'tax2'
}
RETURN c,p,t
```

Then I get only product1 ( which doesn't have tax2 ). This is the behavior that I was expecting from both queries. I know that in the first example, the variable "t" was also used in the subquery, how this affects the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your first query's outer `MATCH` clause binds the `p` and `t` values, the inner `MATCH` clause cannot find anything other than the same `p` and `t` values. In other words, this simpler query is logically equivalent:

```
MATCH (c:company)-[:sells]->(p:product)<-[:taxes]-(t:tax)
WHERE t.name <> 'tax2'
RETURN c,p
```

So, your first query will return a product every time it is taxed by something other than "tax2".

Your second query uses an unbound variable, `t2`, in its inner `MATCH` clause. Therefore, its [existential subquery](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/where/#existential-subqueries) is able to evaluate *all* taxes for each product (not just `t`) before allowing the outer `MATCH` to succeed.